# data-dojo-props='url:" "' seems not working on windows phone 8.1

Tags: dojo, windows-phone-8.1, worklight-studio, dojox.mobile

I made a simple mobile app (using IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.01-20140917-1250). I add for this app the Dojo (using dojo 1.9.3FeP) capabilities.
I build for Android and IOS first.
When both are working, I add windows Phone 8.

After building the app and test it on both windows 8.1 emulator (via Visual Studio 2013 Professional) and Windows Phone 8.1.

I notice that the List view to browse new view using `data-dojo-props='url:""'` are not working.

Code snipped as follow;

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view1" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
                <!--application UI goes here-->
                Hello Worklight
                <br><hr><br>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" >
                <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                    data-dojo-props="label:'Item 1',url:'Page1.html',transition:'slide',dir:'1'"></div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                    data-dojo-props="label:'Item 2',moveTo:'view2',transition:'slide',dir:'1'"></div>
            </div>

            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view2" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
                Hello form View 1.
            </div>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Page1.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="p1V1" >
    <br><hr><span>Hello from Page 1 View 1</span><br><hr>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Item',moveTo:'view1',transition:'slide',dir:'1'">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any known issue for this `data-dojo-props='url:""'` at windows phone 8.1 by using worklight studio 6.1.0.01-20140917-1250?

Update

#### ------------------------------

I've use same code and build by using IBM Mobile first 7 with dojo 1.10.4. Then import to visual studio 2012-update 4 and visual studio 2013 and test it on emulator.
working as expected.

If I use dojo 1.10.4 with IBM worklight Studio 6.1.0.01-20140917-1250, building the project which contains this 2 html files, not finishing even after 20 minutes of building.

I compare the _ItemBase.js and RoundRectList.js include in dojox/mobile between 2 different version (1.9.3Fep and 1.10.4). Their code are same.

The debug result is as follow.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GppFW.jpg

I can't upload image at here since my reputation is less than 10.

Comment: @Idan Adar, thanks for helping me to improve my question. It would be great if you put some comment why you are removing the word related with IBM worklight studio. So that my next questions could be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing newer version of fix pack (IBM Worklight 6.1.02-20150725) from IBM Fixcentral and rebuilt, it work.

My previous answer include link for fix pack to download but deleted as https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjhA5.jpg therefore, please find at search engine for download link.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there were a bunch off issues with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1, which I believed are supposed to be fixed with dojo 1.10.4: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18540

Could you check if dojo 1.10.4 fix your issue ?

Comment: I've updated at my question by adding my latest testing results. Yes. I've tried dojo 1.10.4 .

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 TypeError in your screenshot. What are the files and what lines of code are triggering these errors?